# Product image not displaying in category or search view

Tags: magento

I have a test site where some imported product images are not being displayed on the category view or the search view.

It does however show up on the product page.

These products were imported / updated to reflect new images.

Category view
http://sales.magentocommerce.net.au/index.php/irrigation/driptube.html

Product view page
http://sales.magentocommerce.net.au/index.php/irrigation/driptube/221002-drip-eze-pc-13mm-2l-h-0-3m-50m.html

Other products whose images were uploaded manually is showing up.

All cache has been cleared and disabled in Magento.

What else am I missing.

I suspect the database records got screwed up somewhere on these products.

I am running out of ideas to what else to look out for and need a fresh pair of eyes.

Magento ver. 1.9.0.1

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you forgot to reindex your data.

Go to **System -> Index Management**, click *select all* (or at least select the first four indexes) and then press submit to reindex.

Answer (score 0):

I note your image is almost 2MB. On my shared hosting with 1and1, I cannot use such large images as Magento's image processing (eg producing thumbnails) falls over as it runs out of memory. I therefore have to preprocess any large images to shrink them down to something my Magento can handle.

One other thing, png files tend to be significantly larger than jpg files.